# Как восстановить удалённый файл в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Ребят случайно удалил layout, над которым работал пару месяцев назад, через AndroidStudio.Как можно восстановить файл?

Comment: Привидите в пример код. Ваш вопрос плохо задан и непонятен.

Comment: Удалили в AS или средствами системы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Восстановление файла, удалённого из Android Studio**

1. Кликните правой кнопкой мыши на папку, в которой нужно восстановить файл.
2. В открывшемся контекстном меню наведите курсор на поле **Local History** и выберите пункт **Show History**. Откроется новое окно.

[image: Show History]

3. Слева в списке последних изменений выберите пункт **Deleting**, соответствующий удалению нужного вам файла. Справа будет показана древовидная структура пути к файлу.
4. Нажмите правой кнопкой мыши на имя файла и кликните на **Revert Selection**. После этого файл будет восстановлен.

[image: Revert Selection]

Comment: Дай бог тебе здоровья!