# Android studio откат к последним сохранениям

Tags: android-studio

Как вернуться к последним сохраненным изменениям, чтобы все что было изменено в файлах и сами некоторые файлы были восстановлены до старой версии ?

Comment: Как и в любом другом случае: взять из бэкапа или системы управления версиями (самые популярные из которых встроены в АС).  Если ничего из перечисленного не имеется, то погоревать и задуматься наконец о привычке пользоваться этими необходимыми инструментами.

Comment: есть локальная история (VCS - Local History - show history), но работает она в пределах одной сессии, насколько я помню ([пример использования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/648893/177345)). Для надежных бэкапов и возвратов необходимо использовать систему контроля версий, как git ([пример подключения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/444780/177345))